# Error foreach function: Incorrect number of Dimensions

Tags: r

i want to regress the realized Variance on the 1 myth lagged realized Variance, so i got the following table:

```
 'data.frame':  1018 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Tad   : num  0.00264 0.00368 0.003 0.00131 0.00144 ...
 $ Varlag: num  NA 0.00264 0.00368 0.003 0.00131 ...  


                   Tad      Varlag
1927-02-28 0.002637858          NA
1927-03-31 0.003680607 0.002637858
1927-04-30 0.003000301 0.003680607
1927-05-31 0.001309588 0.003000301
1927-06-30 0.001444917 0.001309588
1927-07-31 0.001299911 0.001444917
```

Since I want to do an Outofsample regression, my regression should be splitted in a regression of the first 240 mths,to predict RV(t=241) and then including every "i"th month. to predict RV(t=240+i)

```
A<-foreach(i=(1:748),.combine = cbind) %do%{
  reg=lm(Non.Over.Real.Var$Tad[1:(240+i-      1),]~Non.Over.Real.Var$Varlag[1:(240+i-1),])
  pred<-predict(reg,Non.Over.Real.Var$Tad[(240+i),])
  return(pred)
}
```

the error witch occurs states task 1 failed, wrong number of Dimensions

So i don't know if i have to use an xts version of my data or a data.frame

So is it my code, the "NA" value (tried already),the class of my data, or my "i" specification?

Comment: can you provide a header of the DF you're using?

Comment: Using `i` inside a formula seems problematic.  Try `lm(Tad ~ Varlag, data = Non.Over.Real.Var[1:(240 + i - 1), ])`

Comment: edited my post,

Comment: And also change predict to `predict(reg, Non.Over.Real.Var[(240+i), ])`.

Comment: but isn't the "i" what i need to do the "foreach" function ?

Comment: predict(reg, Non.Over.Real.Var[(240+i), ]) Shall i ad a "1" for the column since i only want the first column to be predicted (Tad)?